Immediate connect fail for ::1: Cannot assign requested address
I configured certificate authority on localhost in a Docker. But curl --ipv6 -v https://localhost does not work:
*   Trying [::1]:443...
* Immediate connect fail for ::1: Cannot assign requested address
* Failed to connect to localhost port 443 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server

I need IPv6 inside Docker (note that my Docker image does not need IPv6 connections to the outside world).
How to make curl successfully connect to localhost (I mean to the localhost that is inside Docker) through IPv6?
The reason why I need this, is that I am debugging an IPv6-only software and use curl to mock its effect.
The following toy example Docker container demonstrates the problem:
FROM nginx
CMD nginx & sleep 1 && curl --ipv6 -s -v http://localhost

I run it as:
$ docker build . -t test-ipv6 && docker run test-ipv6
...
*   Trying [::1]:80...
* Immediate connect fail for ::1: Cannot assign requested address
* Failed to connect to localhost port 80 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server



What did you start listening on that port? Please provide a [mcve].

@BMitch On this port there is my custom proxy server. Providing a reproducible example of all the Docker container would be hard, and it would contain irrelevant things such as Rust sources. I am asking to fix IPv6 networking in Docker, not to solve my entire software dev task.

Create a minimal example, running something like an nginx container. Include your docker run command.

@BMitch I created the minimal example. See the edited question.

FROM nginx
CMD nginx & sleep 1 && curl --ipv6 -s -v http://localhost

In this example the CMD causes the entrypoint to skip the normal setup. That's because the CMD value gets interpreted as a shell command so $1 becomes /bin/sh. Importantly, that means the /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh script is not run on startup, leaving nginx to only listen on 0.0.0.0:80:
$ docker run -it --rm --network container:7cdf nicolaka/netshoot /bin/sh
~ # ss -lnt
State        Recv-Q        Send-Q               Local Address:Port               Peer Address:Port       
LISTEN       0             511                        0.0.0.0:80                      0.0.0.0:*          
~ # ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host proto kernel_lo 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
195: eth0@if196: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:c0:a8:3f:03 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 192.168.63.3/24 brd 192.168.63.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Another important thing to note from that example is that inside the container, only localhost has an IPv6 address, and the other nic for container to container communication is only IPv4. When accessed from the host, the published port could be listening on IPv6 and forward to the container over IPv4, which is the typical way containers support IPv6:
$ docker run --name nginx --rm -p 8080:80 -d nginx
b8f87cf44d945aee97c7d4c05bab592abc3bcdb4d58698e56e0b2de7612996cc

$ curl --ipv6 -s -v http://localhost:8080
* Host localhost:8080 was resolved.
* IPv6: ::1
* IPv4: 127.0.0.1
*   Trying [::1]:8080...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/8.7.1
> Accept: */*
>
* Request completely sent off
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.27.0
< Date: Fri, 31 May 2024 12:20:54 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 615
< Last-Modified: Tue, 28 May 2024 13:22:30 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< ETag: "6655da96-267"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
<
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
html { color-scheme: light dark; }
body { width: 35em; margin: 0 auto;
font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact

$ docker stop nginx
nginx


